# Shortcut to select a Terminal-window?

Tags: unity, command-line, shortcut-keys, shortcuts, usability

I like to use CTRL-ALT + Numpad-keys to align 4 terminal windows on one monitor (One in each corner of the screen). Is there a way (shortcut) to quickly make a particular one active for typing without clicking the window active with the mouse?

System: Ubuntu 11.04/default Unity desktop

Answer (score 6):

You can also consider using terminator. Terminator is a GPL terminal emulator and allows multiple Gnome terminals in one window. If you are using terminator you can switch terminals with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Arrow</kbd>

To install terminator you can use PPA or use ubuntu tweak.

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome-terminator/ppa
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install terminator

Comment: I'm not sure this is the best answer for the OP, but I also use terminator and recommend it.   You can use Alt-arrows to select windows, and there are other commands to cycle through them.  If you group by tabs, it looks like you can set shortcuts to tab by number, but I've never done this. (Change under Preferences->Keybindings.)  Also, I believe terminator (one rev back) is available in the regular universe repository.

Comment: FYI, it is not necessary to use a PPA to install Terminator. It has been available in the [ubuntu repository](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/terminator/) for some time now.

Answer (score 5):

Alt+the button above Tab and below esc, normally, will switch between the windows of a single application. So, if you have one terminal active, pressing that keyboard combination will switch between your terminals like Alt+tab.

Comment: good shortcut!  It would be called alt-backtick.

Comment: I deliberately avoid that, because it depends on layout. On Norwegian keyboards, it's § and |, for instance. Button Above Tab is more explicit and if you abbreviate it to BAT, then it's TAB in reverse. :) It is a very useful shortcut.

Answer (score 3):

You could always use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to page through windows until you get to the right one.